# Cross Origin Issue while opening image in Editor

Tags: laravel

In Editor image is getting by direct url without any api
the error is

Access to Image at 'http://localhost:8000/storage/postimages/1491006/07-28-2018_0101pm.jpeg' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to get around this.

1. Depending on what web server you are using add the header
   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8000` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` so browsers
   understand and allow cross origin.
2. Some browsers like Chrome doesn't allow cross origin request for
       localhost so try another browser or create another domain name
       locally like example.com to point to 127.0.0.1

Hope this helps.

Comment: kalagen I am using Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
i am working with jwt token